# When connected to 2 networks, how can I query DNS servers from both networks?

Tags: network, dns

My Mac mini is currently connected to 2 networks in the following configuration:

1. Lan1: Internet (Ethernet/DHCP)
2. Lan2: Company intranet companydomain.local (Wi-Fi/DHCP)

Both Lan1 and Lan2 are on different subnets.
Service Order is set to Lan1, Lan2.

I have no problems accessing resources on Lan2 via IP address, but I can't seem to access anything via device name (either name only or name+fqdn).

DNS for Lan1 is set to the router's IP (which forwards ISP DNS)
DNS for Lan2 is set to my company's internal DNS servers and the domain name is also set in "Search Domains"

I would expect that both DNS services should be queried when my computer tries to resolve a name but that's apparently not happening in my case.

I considered changing service order to put my company's connection first, but I don't want to be hitting the company DNS server to resolve anything but the company intranet names, and want to keep my Internet traffic going out over the LAN1 connection.

Is there something I can do to resolve this?